# How to replace global string before compiling in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

Every time I compile my application, I would like to replace a string such as `$(Database)` with `[DatabaseName]` in all files within my solution/project.

I looked at Pre-build events and Macros, but cannot figure out how to add my own key value pair to it. The solution has many sql files that are in need of replacement of a particular variable. Can this be done via RegEx? I know I can do a FindAll/ReplaceAll but that does not address the issue of doing this over and over.

Comment: Sorry, if you don't mind me asking, why don't you just write [DatabaseName] instead of $(Database)?

Comment: The variable needs to change based on the deployment profile.

Comment: Okay, I was confused - the brackets generally refer to attributes in C#. Is there a way you can query that at run-time rather than altering your entire program pre-compilation? This concept seems incredibly brittle.

Comment: I see your point. I inherited this hot mess of an application that uses sql files in a resource file which it then executes. But it has hard coded database names which i would like to replace for testing/deployment.

Comment: Doing replacement at run-time may be much easier (especially if you put replacement string in .config file)... just a thought...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this probably isn't the best solution, but I think it's gonna be better than trying to find some sort of internal solution to replace all instances of a non-code string at compile-time.

The idea is preprocessor directives. You can use the # operator on any line to add a preprocessor directive like so.

One is if/elif/else:

```
#if DEBUG
     // Access your test database here
#else
     // Put your hard-coded database calls in here.
#endif
```

This way, any build of the Debug branch will execute on your test code, and any Release build will execute the original hard-coded database calls.

You can also use your own custom values with #define, like #define MYTESTVARIABLE, after which sections wrapped in #if TESTVARIABLE ... #endif will execute.

Here's the MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx

As I said, this isn't the best option - it definitely increases the amount of code - but I think it might be less brittle than where you were going in your head.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server or ORACLE you could use CREATE SYNONYM to set the name in code so that the code base always references the same name forever so that you do not have to change your code, you just create a SYNONYM on each server for each table or object.

In all cases like you describe I have found a way without using SYNONYM to remove the need for the code file changes during compile.  Thus not needing to ever actually use synonym in situations like you describe.  I am recommending you take a different approach to the problem.  Try not to modify code on each compile.  Usually a config file or runtime tweak is all that is needed.

Also be aware that you may see in generated files "MyDevDatabaseActualName" but in reality you do not have to replace it with the QA or Prod database name.  This name you are replacing is a TypeName that was chosen from your initial database connection and only a config file change is needed to point to a new database.